# How to send mouseover event to parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a Div in which there is a text input, like this:

```
<div id="parentDive" class="parent">
<input id="textbox"></input>
</div>
```

I have assigned a functionality to the Div `mouseover` event and `mouseout` event by means of JQuery, but when I move my mouse over the text input, it calls `mouseout` event while it's in the DIV.

How to solve this problem? Should I send the event to the parent? How?

Comment: Simply bind [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead. By the way, you better specify the input `type` don't let the browser decide.

Comment: would you please explain it more (with an example of code) in form of an answer

Comment: I solved the problem with your help, but please post it in form of an answer, so I can accept your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the jQuery `.hover()` method instead of binding `mouseover` and `mouseout`:

```
$("#parentDive").hover(function() {
    //mouse over parent div
}, function() {
    //mouse out of parent div
});

$("#textbox").hover(function() {
    //mouse over textbox
}, function() {
    //mouse out of textbox
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/g4pQK/1/).

The `.hover()` is actually binding the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, which are what you were looking for.

Comment: How does that answer the question? From what I'm reading, the question was about not getting a mouseleave event in the parent when entering the child...

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to you to use `.hover()` not `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()` here is a live working example
 http://jsfiddle.net/DeUQY/

```
$('.parent').hover(function(){
    alert('mouseenter');
},function(){
    alert('mouseleave');
}

);
```

Comment: `hover` is just a shortcut for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: Sorry it should be `mouseover()` instead of `mouseenter()`, He was using `mouseover()`. I have edited the answer, and this fiddle will answer what he meant http://jsfiddle.net/DeUQY/1/ .

Comment: Should be "not `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()`" you still have to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a few steps to make that work.

First, create the parent hover functions which would be `enter()` and `exit()`. These are setup using the `hover()` function. Then create the children `enterChild()` and `exitChild()` function. The children just change a flag that allows you to know whether a child is being hovered and thus the parent is still being considered to be hovered.

Whatever you want to do in the `exit()` function, you cannot do it immediately because the events arrive in the *correct* order for a GUI, but the wrong order for this specific case:

```
enter parent
exit parent
enter child
exit child
enter parent
exit parent
```

So when your `exit()` function gets called, you may be entering the child right after and if you want to process something when **both** the parent and child are exited, just acting on the `exit()` will surely be wrong. Note that the browser is written in such a way that an exit event always happens if an enter event happened. The only exception may be if you close the tab/window in which case they may forfeit sending more events.

So, in the parent `exit()` function we make use of a `setTimeout()` call to make an asynchronous call which will happen after the `enter()` function of a child happens. This means we can set a flag there and test it in the asynchronous function.

```
MyNamespace = {};

MyNamespace.MyObject = function()
{
    var that = this;

    // setup parent
    jQuery(".parentDiv").hover(
        function()
        {
            that.enter_();
        },
        function()
        {
            that.exit_();
        });

    // setup children
    jQuery(".parentDiv .children").hover(
        function()
        {
            that.enterChild_();
        },
        function()
        {
            that.exitChild_();
        });
}

// couple variable members
MyNamespace.MyObject.prototype.parentEntered_ = false;
MyNamespace.MyObject.prototype.inChild_ = false;

MyNamespace.MyObject.prototype.enter_ = function()
{
    // WARNING: if the user goes really fast, this event may not
    //          happen, in that case the childEnter_() calls us
    //          so we use a flag to make sure we enter only once
    if(!this.parentEntered_)
    {
        this.parentEntered_ = true;

        ... do what you want to do when entering (parent) ...
    }
};

// NO PROTOTYPE, this is a static function (no 'this' either)
MyNamespace.MyObject.realExit_ = function(that) // static
{
    if(!that.inChild_)
    {
         ... do what you want to do when exiting (parent) ...

         that.parentEntered_ = false;
    }
};

MyNamespace.MyObject.prototype.exit_ = function()
{
    // need a timeout because otherwise the enter of a child
    // does not have the time to change inChild_ as expected
    setTimeout(MyNamespace.MyObject.realExit_(this), 0);
};

// detect when a child is entered
MyNamespace.MyObject.prototype.enterChild_ = function()
{
    this.inChild_ = true;
    this.enter_(); // in case child may be entered directly
};

// detect when a child is exited
MyNamespace.MyObject.prototype.exitChild_ = function()
{
    this.inChild_ = false;

    // We cannot really do this, although in case the child
    // is "exited directly" you will never get the call to
    // the 'exit_()' function; I'll leave as an exercise for
    // you in case you want it (i.e. use another setTimeout()
    // but save the ID and clearTimeout() if exit_() is not
    // necessary...)
    //this.exit_()
};
```